# Vim Visual Mode - is there a way to change the background color only when in visual mode?

Tags: vim, editors

I forgot which mode I am in using VIM so I set this up in my `.vimrc` so that I easily know I am in Insert mode as the background changes to Yellow

```
:au InsertEnter * hi Normal term=reverse ctermbg=darkgrey guibg=yellow "
:au InsertLeave * hi Normal term=NONE    ctermbg=black    guibg=white "
```

How can I do something similar for when I am in Visual mode? Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 2):

There are no corresponding autocmds for entering / leaving visual mode (yet; someone recently requested such on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php)).

Therefore, you can only evaluate `mode()` (e.g. in `'statusline'`), or emulate (unfortunately, only incompletely) this by overloading the mappings that enter / exit visual mode, as seen here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561132/run-command-when-vim-enters-visual-mode
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165350/how-to-emulate-autocmd-visualleave-or-autocmd-visualenter-in-vim